# what is the jargon of the alias variable after import module in Python?

Tags: python, terminology

There are lots of packages in Python ecosystem, like NumPy, Matplotlib.

to simplify coding, we usually code this way

```
import numpy as np
```

np is an alias, or shortcut, or something else.

the question is, what is the jargon of this usage? an link to [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) would be great.

Comment: Note that after import the name ``numpy`` is fundamentally the same as the name ``np`` as far as Python is concerned. Both ``numpy`` and ``np`` are local aliases for the underlying module object. Python simply uses the identifier of modules as the default name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing is a form of [name binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding); names in the current namespace are bound to imported objects.

The [`import` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) calls it an *identifier*, but [identifiers *are* names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). Importing an object always binds to an identifier, but the `as <identifier>` syntax lets you specify an alternate name to use instead of the default.

When parsing Python syntax into an Abstract Syntax Tree (which is what the CPython compiler does, and you can do with the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)), then the resulting `Import` and `ImportFrom` nodes have 1 or more `names`, each an object of the `ast.alias` type:

```
      | Import(alias* names)
      | ImportFrom(identifier? module, alias* names, int? level)
```

and the `alias` type has a `name` and an `asname` value, both identifiers, and `asname` is optional:

```
    -- import name with optional 'as' alias.
    alias = (identifier name, identifier? asname)
```

So they are just *names*, variables, and because they differ from the default for those imports, it's fine to call them aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be wrong if you call it `asname`.

[image]