# Python module has no attribute error when importing with an 'as'

Tags: python

I want to import Keras from the Tensorflow library. So I did the following thing :

```
import tensorflow.python.keras as keras
```

But this import throws the error :

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

It appears that both the following import work correctly :

```
import tensorflow.python.keras
from tensorflow.python import keras
```

For me, `import tensorflow.python.keras as keras` and `from tensorflow.python import keras` are identical but it look like it's not true. What is the difference between these two imports ?

Comment: `import tensorflow.python.keras as keras` works for me with `tensorflow==1.13.1` and `Python 3.7.3`

Comment: Can you post your tf version and Python's?

Comment: I am using `Python 3.6` and `tensorflow==1.13.1`

Comment: see , how to import  `keras` https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#import_tfkeras

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow 

from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
# ...
```

The first line helps you use the `tensorflow` module with the `tf` short name (asname).

For the asname you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039383/what-is-the-jargon-of-the-alias-variable-after-import-module-in-python/).